# C - computing sum and multiply it by sizeof in malloc()

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, sizeof, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a question about the allocation of memory in the `malloc()`. I have an int value `k`. What is the difference between allocating in these ways

```
...=(int*)malloc(k*sizeof(int));
```

and

```
...=(int*)malloc(((2*k-1)-k+1)*sizeof(int));
```

knowing that `(2*k-1)-k+1) == k`?

The result of both is the same or in the second case, even if `((2*k-1)-k+1) == k`, can change something?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

That said, `malloc()` takes the argument for the number of bytes of memory to be allocated.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.4, *The `malloc()` function*

> `void *malloc(size_t size);`
>
> The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by `size` [...]

So, as long as `x` and `y` evaluates to same value,

```
malloc(x * sizeof(sometype))
```

and

```
malloc(y * sizeof(sometype))
```

will give you pointers with same amount of memory to be accessed, provided the calls are success.

Finally, it's always better approach to not to use hardcoded values for the `sizeof` operator, rather use the variable itself. Makes the code more robust, like

```
  int *p = NULL;
  .
  .
  .
  p = malloc (x * sizeof(*p));  // type of `p` can change, 
                                // this statement need not be changed
```

Comment: By using hardcoded values can result as segmentation fault in some cases?

Comment: @D3m only if you fail to check for the success of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

Although mathematically equivalent to `k`, the product `(2*k-1)-k+1` may overflow resulting in undefined behavior.  A difference for half of the `int` range versus using `k`.

```
... = malloc(((2*k-1)-k+1)*sizeof(int))
```

`k*sizeof(int)` product itself make overflow, but the product is well-defined, even if not desirable.

The possibility of overflow depends on the range of `size_t` vs. `int`.  `size_t` is typically twice the positive range of `int` and perhaps many times more.  Rarely is it less.  Recommend:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof *p * k);
```

Notes:

1. Casting the result of `malloc()` is not needed.
2. Using `sizeof *p` rather than `sizeof(int)` is less likely to mis-code, easier to review and maintain.
3. Having `sizeof *p` first insures much of the following math to occur using at least `size_t` math.